# How to set both secure and samesite:strict in cookie creation?

Tags: javascript, cookies, samesite

I am trying to get this line to work in JS:

`document.cookie = cname+ "=" +cvalue+ ";" +expires+ " ;path=/;  Secure; SameSite=strict";`

When I try this, I get the following console output:

Cookie “cookieName” will be soon rejected because it has the “SameSite” attribute set to “None” or an invalid value, without the “secure” attribute.

I am not using secure with None, I am using secure with Strict for SameSite. What exactly is going on here, and can I use samesite:strict and secure:true without needing to change that strict to none?

Answer (score -2):

Try:

```
SameSite=Strict; Secure;
```

This worked for me!

Check the order.
Secure starts with an capital letter.
After Strict an secure is a semicolon.
Do you also submit a date for expires (expires = ?)
See my comment below with an working example that I have in production.

An you can see also here:
[samesite-examples in JavaScript by GoogleChromeLabs](https://github.com/GoogleChromeLabs/samesite-examples/blob/master/javascript.md)

Comment: Good suggestion but if you read the question you can see the asker is already using both the `Secure` and `SameSite=Strict` flags. If you are suggesting a change in capitalization you should update your answer to reflect this.

Comment: Sure I saw that. But you did not see the difference to my post. He uses another order and wrote 'strict' not with capital letter. This might be the problem. I can just say that it works for me. So better give it a try. And there is also a semicolon missing behind the strict.

Comment: I use it successful like this: document.cookie = 'AllOn' + FEBE + '=' + AllOnAry + '; expires=' + CookLifTm.toUTCString() + '; path=/' + '; SameSite=Strict; Secure;';

Comment: If you read RFC6265, section 4.1.1 (https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6265#section-4.1.1), you'll find the syntax definition for a cookie. The trailing semicolon is not required nor is the order important. Capitalization does matter, though, and that's the most likely source of the asker's issue.